# Edit Gimp source code for personal requirements

Tags: gimp, source-code, source, editing

I wanna edit gimp source code for my personal specific requirements that are custom printing related, is there any way i can download edit and compile gimp code for windows and ubuntu...?

Comment: http://www.gimp.org/source/ --- are you *really* sure? Good luck...

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? You may find that writing a [GIMP plugin](http://developer.gimp.org/writing-a-plug-in/1/) is a better route.

Comment: i wanna override the part where gimp goes on for printing and edit the final document to simple binary array readable by my usb connected custom controller

Comment: Any reason why you want to do that via print, and not by a file exporter plug-in?

Comment: its not a necessity, i just considered it a good starting point, but main concern is producing a final windows compatible .exe file

Comment: MinGW offers ability to compile windows exe files in linux, but Ive Used it, and it isnt perfect. you might go download visual studio and work with the source from there.

Comment: j0h, there have never been many people to build the GIMP source code with Visual Studio at all - and to my knowledge, there is none doing that at the moment. The binaries for the official GIMP Windows installers are built with MinGW on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the terminal:

```
$sudo apt-get source gimp
```

you'll end up with something like:
gimp_2.8.14-1.debian.tar.xz  gimp_2.8.14-1.dsc  gimp_2.8.14.orig.tar.bz2

you can decompress the files, and modify them at your leisure. 
(compiling, in future, not guaranteed.)
if you do modify the source, and recompile, I recommend running from a local directory rather than installing over the system version. At least until you know your mods are stable.

Comment: say i m done with the editing part, how would i then extract the .exe version of gimp for installation on windows....also it ll be nice if you could give a link for "running from local directory" instructions, the method i know is "make" and "make install" way....Thanks

Comment: You can unpack the installers with a reasonably capable archiving application - 7zip, for example.

Comment: if you want to compile windows binaries in Linux you'll need minGW  or something like that. windows libraries aren't the same as linux libraries.  A good start, is to read the README file that is in the source-code

Comment: Thanks, rite now i m stuck at "make" stage...this is the error...../usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so: error: undefined reference to 'g_module_build_path'

Comment: This maybe a new question at this point. but, since we're here, 
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html
can you verify you have libgtk-x11-2.0‌​.so and that the path is correct? it may be looking to the header in some other location.

Comment: i do have libgtk-x11-2.0‌​.so in my /usr/lib , but i dont know where the compiler is looking for it and how to change it

Comment: All you have to do is make sure that it gets linked with the right libraries. The real bug is in the pgkconfig file for gtk2. So all you have to do is open it as root and add -lgobject-2.0 to the list of libraries. Then rerun configure, make clean and then make all and it will work perfectly.